# How to add controller on mininet

Tags: mininet, openflow

Hi :) I'm a newbie on openflow & mininet.

I experiment my network. And I established my virtual network using mininet.

```
sudo mn
```

And on this existing network, I want to add one more controller.
I heard

```
mininet> py net.addController('c1')
```

above code make my wish come true. But it is failed

```
'list' object is not callable
```

Other similar method is working well like py net.addHost('h3').

Is there solution to solve my problem or any other method to add controller dynamically on existing mininet?

Answer (score 3):

You should define the controller when you run the `mn` command. Try this

`sudo mn --controller remote,ip=127.0.0.1`

The commands that you write are for custom topologies written in python. For [example](https://inside-openflow.com/2016/06/29/custom-mininet-topologies-and-introducing-atom/) you have `topo.py` file

```
from mininet.cli import CLI
from mininet.log import setLogLevel
from mininet.net import Mininet
from mininet.topo import Topo
from mininet.node import RemoteController, OVSSwitch

class MinimalTopo( Topo ):
    "Minimal topology with a single switch and two hosts"

    def build( self ):
        # Create two hosts.
        h1 = self.addHost( 'h1' )
        h2 = self.addHost( 'h2' )

        # Create a switch
        s1 = self.addSwitch( 's1' )

        # Add links between the switch and each host
        self.addLink( s1, h1 )
        self.addLink( s1, h2 )

def runMinimalTopo():
    "Bootstrap a Mininet network using the Minimal Topology"

    # Create an instance of our topology
    topo = MinimalTopo()

    # Create a network based on the topology using OVS and controlled by
    # a remote controller.
    net = Mininet(
        topo=topo,
        controller=lambda name: RemoteController( name, ip='127.0.0.1' ),
        switch=OVSSwitch,
        autoSetMacs=True )

    # Actually start the network
    net.start()

    # Drop the user in to a CLI so user can run commands.
    CLI( net )

    # After the user exits the CLI, shutdown the network.
    net.stop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # This runs if this file is executed directly
    setLogLevel( 'info' )
    runMinimalTopo()

# Allows the file to be imported using `mn --custom <filename> --topo minimal`
topos = {
    'minimal': MinimalTopo
}
```

and you run it like this

`sudo mn --custom topo.py --topo minimal`